# espaçamento entre as barras em um código de barras

Tags: delphi

Possuo o código abaixo que me gera um copio de barras apartir de um numero inserido, porem estou achando que as barras estão muito proximas,
existe uma maneira de deixar elas com um espaçamento maior entre elas?

abaixo o código:

```
const digitos : array['0'..'9'] of string[5]= ('00110', '10001', '01001', '11000', '00101', '10100', '01100', '00011', '10010', '01010');
 var s : string; i, j, x, t : Integer;
  begin // Gerar o valor para desenhar o código de barras //
   s := '0000';
   for i := 1 to length(codigo)div 2 do
   for j := 1 to 5 do s := s + Copy(Digitos[codigo[i * 2 - 1]], j, 1) + Copy(Digitos[codigo[i * 2]], j, 1);
   s := s + '100';
    x := 0;
   Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
    Canvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
    Canvas.Rectangle(0,0, 2000, 79);
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
     Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
     for i := 1 to length(s) do
      begin
      t := strToInt(s[i]) * 3 + 1;
      if i mod 2 = 1 then
      Canvas.Rectangle(x, 0, x + t, 67);
      x := x + t;
      end;
      end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altera conforme demostrado. E crie uma variável espessura e dê valor a ela e veja se fica do jeito que você precisa.

```
const digitos : array['0'..'9'] of string[5]= ('00110', '10001', '01001',  
'11000', '00101', '10100', '01100', '00011', '10010', '01010');  
var s : string; i, j, x, t : Integer;  
begin // Gerar o valor para desenhar o código de barras //  
s := '0000';  
for i := 1 to length(codigo)div 2 do   
for j := 1 to 5 do s := s + Copy(Digitos[codigo[i * 2 - 1]], j, 1) + 
Copy(Digitos[codigo[i * 2]], j, 1);
s := s + '100';
x := 0;
Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
Canvas.Rectangle(0,0, 2000, 79);
Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
for i := 1 to length(s) do
begin
```

> t := strToInt(s[i]) * 3 + 1; altere para  "t := strToInt(s[i]) * 2 + espessura;"

```
if i mod 2 = 1 then
Canvas.Rectangle(x, 0, x + t, 67);
x := x + t;
end;
end;
```